# Creating canonical URL dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have two domains www.example.com and www.example.net pointing to the same website. www.example.com is my primary domain (main domain). I want to set the canonical URL on all pages such that whenever user / bot is seeing the pages on www.example.net, the canonical element is rendered and points to pages on www.example.com.

Example: If a user is viewing the page www.example.net/pagename the canonical element should be rendered pointing to www.example.com/pagename

```
<link href="https://www.example.com/pagename" rel="canonical">
```

So, the pagename will be dynamic and will change for each page.

Can this be achieved using JavaScript? If not, can we do the same using C# as the site is built on Asp.Net MVC / Umbraco.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly suggest you do not do it with javascript. This would mean the bot would have to run the javascript to get the url which doesn't happen often. You can do it directly in the view with something like

```
<link href='@("https://www.example.com" + Request.RawUrl)' rel="canonical">
```

Comment: @CourageousHeart when you can, just accept the answer to help others :)

Comment: _"This would mean the bot would have to run the javascript to get the url which doesn't happen often"_ -- I'm not sure how true this is in 2022, at least for Google-- [Google has a page devoted to SEO and JS](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/javascript/javascript-seo-basics?csw=1) and it seems to be part of their standard crawl/index process.

Comment: What is that @ syntax? I have never seen that before and can't find any documentation.